# Thread connection makes system slow?

Tags: java, tcp, cpu

Friends !!!

I am working on GPS device tracking software. We have almost 3000 devices which is communicates with our server via Java TCP listener. I am creating a separate thread for each device, since once connection establish with device, i don't want to loose connection with device, since it takes time to again create connection.

Once i run my TCP listener, CPU utilization increases 99% and system become unstable. Please help me to find a solution :
A. to write TCP listener in java which can handle more than 3000 thread connection for 3000 devices
B. To minimize CPU utilization.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A is the wrong way and it implicates B. Unless your server runs on a sort of endlessly scalable host farm, you should not create a thread to process every incoming request. You do not mention what kind of connection you exactly have in mind, but in general: the right way is to design a server which uses certain (small) constant amount of threads (for your scale one would probably do) to listen to incoming connections, and serve them by [I/O-bound asynchronous operations](http://www.google.com/search?&q=asynchronous%20input%20output) which do not consume CPU time at all.

Comment: Dear Paul, thanks for reply, But we have 3000 GPS device with communicates with our TCP server continuously and at a time, we can not create one thread to process all incoming request, therefore i created one thread per device. Please let me kn0w how could i design a server to handle all request and must be high performance too.

Comment: Huch, hard to explain in this comment view... The general rule is: Do not spend CPU time while system is doing I/O, only spend CPU time for processing request data. I tried to avoid a .NET-ish answer but I can't: There, each I/O bound resource has a pair of BeginX/EndX methods which serve exactly this purpose. For example a `Socket` offers `BeginReceive/EndReceive` and `BeginSend/EndSend` protocols which do not consume CPU time while waiting until the I/O subsystem request is processed. Hasn't @D.Shawley's answer point you to the right path?

Comment: Dear Paul, I don't now MINA will be helpful or not, Since our device sends the packet in different format and MINA expect end character format to process data. so i am not sure, i am expecting that my listener must be capable to read all incoming request. Thanks

Comment: I just looked up MINA and it looks like it is targeting exactly this problem. I can't help you with details though. I assume there will be several alternatives available out-of-the-box in the Java world - you will have to compare and analyse which one suits best your needs, which one is the most frequently used etc.. After you know what your looking for (you do, right?) get in contact with your Java colleagues, study manuals and ask more specific questions here on SO...

Answer (score 0):

Give [*The C10K Problem*](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) a read.  Look [here](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html#threads.java) and [here](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html#java) for some Java specific notes.

You want to use Java's non-blocking IO layer to handle large connection loads.  The docs from [JDK 1.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/)  are a good starting point.

Comment: Dear Shawley, can we use apache MINA project for this purpose, as it is NIO library.

Comment: @user405575 Yes, MINA is designed to handle this sort of problem.